# Why does this database synchronization routine fail?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, concurrency, synchronization

I've got a database that maintains Jobs to be processed by various processing machines. Its basic schema is thus:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| EndTime     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| GroupID     | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| HostAddress | varchar(15)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| StartTime   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

ID is auto-increment, HostAddress represents the processing machine which has claimed this Job, StartTime represents the beginning of the most recent attempt at processing it, EndTime is the time at which it successfully completed processing, and GroupID is an arbitrary string for referencing other tables with.

All of the processing machines synchronize around this table for grabbing work. New records are only inserted manually, although all of the processing machines can update existing records. The idea was to have a processing machine do the following whenever it's out of work:

- See if any jobs belong to it (HostAddress = its IP) and have yet to be started.
- If there are none, see if any jobs have yet to be claimed (HostAddress IS NULL).
- If there are unclaimed jobs, claim some (update HostAddress to its IP).
- Process all jobs that belong to it (same check as #1 except that we may have added some via #3).

I had thought that this sequence of operations would cause the database to synchronize different machines' attempts at the same job for me; even if both machines tried to claim the same job at the same time, only one of their IPs would end up in the HostAddress column, so when they asked again for all jobs at their HostAddress only one of them would get that job back.

But that does not appear to be the case. When starting 35 processing machines nearly simultaneously last night, I observed multiple cases of multiple machines processing the same job, even though only one of them ended up with it claimed in the database. That implies to me that the last check isn't working properly. Here's the more concrete version of what I'm doing. The database calls use em.createNamedQuery which I'm just going to summarize below them for brevity. JPA is being provided by Hibernate 3.6.8 and the database is MySQL 5.1.61.

```
protected void poll(EntityManager em) {
    List<JobRecord> candidates = null;
    //Synchronized only for this machine. Others are running concurrently.
    synchronized (em) {
        //Check if anything is already claimed by us.
        candidates = JobRecord.selectReady(em);
        //SELECT record FROM JobRecord record WHERE HostAddress=[IP]
        //    AND StartTime IS NULL AND EndTime IS NULL;
            if (candidates.isEmpty()) {
            //None claimed. Check if any jobs aren't claimed by anyone.
            candidates = JobRecord.selectAvailable(em);
            //SELECT record FROM JobRecord record WHERE HostAddress IS NULL
            //    AND StartTime IS NULL AND EndTime IS NULL;
            if (candidates.isEmpty()) {
                //All jobs have been processed.
                return;
            }
            //Claim these jobs we found for ourselves.
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            for (JobRecord job : candidates) {
                job.setStartTime(null);
                job.setEndTime(null);
                job.setHostAddress([IP]);
                em.merge(job);
            }
            em.getTransaction().commit;
            //Only process what is actually claimed by us; could be nothing.
            candidates = JobRecord.selectReady(em);
            //(The first query again.)
        }
    //Do processing with candidates list.
}
```

The only explanation that comes to mind is that when I do the em.getTransaction().commit the results are cached somehow, and that when I do the selectReady NamedQuery just after it, it's returning the cached result *without bothering to consult the database*. But that might not even be the case, and I'm not sure I could prove that. There might even be something fundamentally flawed with my scheme that I'm overlooking.

So, to actually pose my question, why did this database synchronization routine fail and what can I do to correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple machines can invoke `selectAvailable()` before any of them perform the `UPDATE` transaction.  Consequently, they may each think that the same jobs are available.

You need to begin the transaction before the `selectAvailable()` call, which should use [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) in order to lock the available job records so that no other database connection can read from them until the transaction is committed.

Comment: Ah! I think I've got the bit I was missing. I was expecting multiple machines could SELECT the same job and that multiple machines would try to UPDATE it, but I was assuming that because only one HostAddress ends up in the DB that only one HostAddress would be read back by the final SELECT. But I forgot that it could temporarily actually have one value in the DB, reread that value and begin processing, then another could do its pending update and afterward reread the new value. I'll look into FOR UPDATE a bit more, but this ought to do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: I think another important thing to note is that, if I understand it correctly, the SELECT ... FOR UPDATE and the UPDATE itself need to be part of the same Transaction. Otherwise it would lock rows, not do anything with them, and unlock them before updating, at which point another machine could still swoop in.

Comment: @HammerBro.: Doesn't my answer say that? "*begin the transaction before the `selectAvailable()` call ... in order to lock ... until the transaction is committed*" ;P

Comment: Haha, so it does. I've been thinking about this problem from a handful of different angles, so my head's swimming a little bit. I actually think I found a way to do it purely in JPA (which probably translates into FOR UPDATE but is a little more proper); I may edit that solution onto my question if it appears to work out.

Comment: @HammerBro.: Definitely do that.  I'm not a Java developer, so there may well be more Java-esque ways of accomplishing this.  The principle is sound, though.